# my provider is not found, when I use selector

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I run the below code using consumer and provider and it worked smoothly but when I add selector it geive me an error,
the error:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Selector<SignInUpProvider, int> Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'providers/sign_in_up_provider.dart';
import 'utilities/myColors.dart' ;
 class SigInUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SigInUpPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SigInUpPageState createState() => _SigInUpPageState();
}

class _SigInUpPageState extends State<SigInUpPage> {




   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context)=> SignInUpProvider(),
     child: const SignInUpScreen(),);

  }


}
class SignInUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignInUpScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignInUpScreenState createState() => _SignInUpScreenState();
}

class _SignInUpScreenState extends State<SignInUpScreen> {


  // determine the sign in or sign up screen!!
  // 0 = sign up , 1 = sign in
   // sign up contents
  // final  GlobalKey<FormState> _keySignUp = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final   TextEditingController _nameSignUp = TextEditingController();
  final   TextEditingController _passSignup = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _emailSignUp = TextEditingController();
  // sign in contents
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _keySignIn = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController  _emailSignIn = TextEditingController();
  final      TextEditingController _passSifnIn = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _nameSignUp.dispose();
    _passSifnIn.dispose();
    _passSignup.dispose();
    _emailSignIn.dispose();
    _emailSignUp.dispose();


    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            // dummy design
            firstScreen(context),
            // dummy design
            secondScreen(context),
            // sign in screen
            thirdScreen(context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
  // first background in stack
  Widget firstScreen(BuildContext context){
    return
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        color:MyColors.blueColor(),
      );

  }
  // second background in stack
  Widget secondScreen(BuildContext context){
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      child: Container(
        decoration:   BoxDecoration(
            color: MyColors.purple(),

            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft:Radius.circular(1000),
                topLeft: Radius.circular(1000)
            )
        ),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      ),
    );
  }
  // sign in up screen // the white box
  Widget thirdScreen(BuildContext context){
    return Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.7,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.7,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))),
          child: Selector<SignInUpProvider, int>(
            selector: (context, userState) => userState.getUserState,
            builder: (context, state, widget){
            return Form(
              key: _keySignIn,
              child: (state == 0 )?
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children:

                [
                  logo(context),
                  nameBox(context),
                  emailBox(context),
                  passText(context),
                  signButton(context),
                  // this to change between sign in and sign up
                  changeState(context),

                ],
              ):
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children:

                [
                  logo(context),
                  emailBox(context),
                  passText(context),
                  signButton(context),
                  // this to change between sign in and sign up
                  changeState(context),

                ],
              ),
            );
            }
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
// the logo inside the white box
  Widget logo(context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))
      ),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.7,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1,
      child: const Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("mekyajat",style: TextStyle(
            fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
            fontSize: 16,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(249, 229, 230, 1),
          ),)),
    );
  }
  // name box
  Widget nameBox(context){
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.55,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white70,
      ),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller:_nameSignUp ,
        decoration:   const InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          hintText: "name",
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black12,
              fontSize: 14
          ),

        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        validator: (value){
          if(  value.toString().length < 8 ){
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "please insert your name \n more than 8 charecters",
                gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16
            );
          }   return null ;
        },

      ),
    );
  }

  Widget  emailBox(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.55,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white70,
      ),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller:(context.read<SignInUpProvider>().getUserState
            == 0) ? _emailSignUp : _emailSignIn ,
        decoration:   const InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(Icons.email_outlined),
          hintText: "E-mail @",
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black12,
              fontSize: 14
          ),

        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        validator: (value){
          if(  value.toString().length < 10 ){
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "please insert your email \n ",
                gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16
            );
          }
          else if (!containSymbol(value.toString(), "@")){
            return "please insert @ symbol";
          }
          return null ;
        },

      ),

    );

  }

  Widget passText(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.55,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white70,
      ),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller:(context.read<SignInUpProvider>().getUserState ==0)? _passSignup :_passSifnIn ,
        decoration:   const InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(Icons.password_sharp),
          hintText: "password",
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black12,
              fontSize: 14
          ),

        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        validator: (value){
          if(  value.toString().length < 8 ){
            Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "please insert your password \n more than 8 charecters",
                gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16
            );
          }   return null ;
        },

      ),

    );

  }

  Widget signButton(BuildContext context) {
    return Selector<SignInUpProvider, int>(
      selector: (context,userState)=> userState.getUserState,
    builder: (context, currentState, widget){
    return  InkWell(
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.40,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.06,
          child: (currentState == 0 )?
          const Text("SIGN UP", textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),):
          const Text("SIGN IN",textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
          decoration:  BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
            gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
               MyColors.blueColor(),
              MyColors.purple(),


                 ]),



          ),
        ),
        onTap: (){},
      );
    },
    );
  }

  Widget changeState(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<SignInUpProvider>(

     builder: (context, userSt , widget){
       return InkWell(
         child: SizedBox(
             width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.55,
             height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.05,
             child:(userSt.userState == 0)?
             const Text("sign in",
               textAlign: TextAlign.right,
               style: TextStyle(color:Color.fromRGBO(205, 221, 232, 1),fontSize: 12,
               ),) :
             const Text("sign up",
               textAlign: TextAlign.right,
               style: TextStyle(
                 color:Color.fromRGBO(205, 221, 232, 1),fontSize: 12,
               ),)

         ),
         onTap: (){
           userSt.changeUserState(userSt.userState);
           // SignInUpProvider().changeUserState(userState);
           // signProvider.changeUserState(signProvider.userState);

         },
       );
     },
     );
  }
}

// provide this function with one char and one string
// this run to see if the string contains char or not
bool containSymbol(String fullString ,  String char){
   bool _result = false ;
   List<String> _chars = [];
   int _stringLingth = fullString.length;
   int _keyLoop = 0 ;
   while (_keyLoop < _stringLingth){
     _chars.add(fullString[_keyLoop]);
     _keyLoop++;
   }
   for(int x = 0 ; x < _chars.length; x++){
     if(_chars[x] == char){
       _result = true;
       break;
     }
   }

   return _result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1 - move up your ChangeNotifierProvider step above in the widget tree for example in the routes you can wrap the SigInUpPage like this :

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<SignInUpProvider>(
        create: (_) => SignInUpProvider(),
        child: SigInUpPage(),
        ),
```

2 - don't pass the context as a parameter to the other screens,use a builder in each screen like this for the second screen:

```
class secondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
    const secondScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.1),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.7,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.7,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))),
                  child: Selector<SignInUpProvider, int>(
                selector: (context, userState) =>       userState.getUserState,
                builder: (context, state, widget){
                  return Form(
                    key: _keySignIn,
                    child: (state == 0 )?
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children:
  
                      [
                        logo(context),
                        nameBox(context),
                        emailBox(context),
                        passText(context),
                        signButton(context),
                        // this to change between sign in and sign up
                        changeState(context),

                      ],
                    ):
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children:
  
                      [
                        logo(context),
                        emailBox(context),
                        passText(context),
                        signButton(context),
                        // this to change between sign in and sign up
                        changeState(context),

                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

  }
```

this should work

Comment: it doesn't work, the same error @Ma Jeed

Comment: I have edited my answer, see if it works now